# AndroidAnnotation REST handling callbacks

Tags: java, android, rest, android-annotations

I'm working on an Android application using AndroidAnnotation.

The app make REST calls to my remote API. So I setup AA and my REST client. But I want to write generic code for handling response data.

I got a RestClient class where the @Rest annotation is defined
a RestCall class where functions to be call with params and callback function
and I guess i need to code an interface called ResponseHandler for eventslistener.

The way I want to use my RestClient is simple, i just want to be able to do so: (like javascript)

```
@Click
public buttonId(){
    //button clicked makes api call
    RestCall.callUserItems(user_id, new ResponseHandler(){
        @Overide
        onSuccess(items){/* CODE TO EXEC ON UITHREAD FOR ITEMS */}
        @Overide
        onError(error object){/* CODE TO EXEC ON UITHREAD FOR ERRORS */}
    });
}
```

but i don't know how to build the handler interface listening for receive datas event from my RestClient, and i dunno how to pass generic objects types..

I hope I'm clear on my explanations.

Can you help me ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, this may not be the answer you are looking for,

but I would recommend using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to handle the REST calls.

Comment: Has you advise, i'm now using retrofit that is easier to implement. Thanks, it's working as expected now :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it that way:

```
try {
    RestCall.callUserItems(user_id);
} catch (RestClientException e) {
  // handle error for Rest client exceptions
}
```